# How to set select icon bigger

Tags: html, css

I want to set "icon select" bigger than the default size. I have no idea how to do that in CSS.

I want to change this : [image]

to this one :

[image]

```
                             <select class="form-control">
                                    <option>test</option>
                                    <option>2</option>
                                    <option>3</option>
                                    <option>4</option>
                                    <option>5</option>
                                </select>
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Where is your sample code?

Comment: We need the CSS to answer a question involving CSS and has CSS and CSS3 tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know two basic workarounds for this problem:

```css
/* 1st */
.form-control {
 width: 150px;
 padding: 2px;
 background-image: url(http://aki.ovh/dl/down.png); /* replace with anything */
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 98% center;
}
/* 2nd */
.container {
    width:150px; height:23px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 1px solid rgb(169, 169, 169);
 display: inline-block;
}
.form-control-2 {
    width:170px;
    padding:2px;
 border:none;
 outline: none !important;
 background-image: url(http://aki.ovh/dl/down.png); /* replace with anything */
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 130px center;
}
```

```html
<h2>1st<h2>
<div>
<select class="form-control">
<option>test</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
</div>
<h2>2nd</h2>
<div class="container">
    <select class="form-control-2">
        <option>lorem</option>
        <option>ipsum</option>
        <option>dolor</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I hope one of them will help you.

First workaround works in really, really simple way. The new icon we have added with `background` covers the original icon. Due to different styles of this button in different browser I suggest **not** to use this solution (it will work properly only in Chrome/browsers without solid button there).

Second workaround is a little bit more complicated as it hides the original part with icon using `overflow: hidden` in our `.container` and then we add new icon with `background` and proper positioning.

Further information for 2nd workaround: [here](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/).

Comment: fyi, the first example is broken in firefox

Comment: It is. Was tested on chrome and as stated somewhere in post is not cross-browser wise. It is just meant to give some idea of how you can make it work. Also I have edited answer to make it more clear that it is not cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 0):

try to use in icon styling font-size as in px it makes bigger your icon

```
.icon
{
fonts-size:20px /* as much as you want */
}
```